# ERROR AL ACCEDER A LA BASE DE DATOS DE MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysqldb

como se encuentran, me encuentro presentando un problema con mi codigo ya que me esta dando un acceso denegado a la base de datos dandome como error MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'migue'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")  sin embargo, primero el mi codigo no estoy usando el usuario 'migue' si no que utilizo el de root, adjunto mi codigo para la conexion a la base de datos:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
mysql=MySQL()


app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST']='localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER']='root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD']=''
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB']='sitio'

mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/')
def inicio():
    return render_template('sitio/index.html')


@app.route('/libros')
def libros():
    return render_template('sitio/libros.html')

@app.route('/nosotros')
def nosotros():
    return render_template('sitio/nosotros.html')


@app.route('/admin/')
def admin_index():
    return render_template('admin/index.html')

@app.route('/admin/login')
def admin_login():
    return render_template('admin/login.html')

@app.route('/admin/libros')
def admin_libros():
    conexion = mysql.connect()
    print(conexion)
    return render_template('admin/libros.html')

@app.route('/admin/libros/guardar', methods=['POST'])
def admin_libros_guardar():
    _nombre=request.form['txtNombre']
    _url=request.form['txtURL']
    _archivo=request.files['txtImagen']

    sql="INSERT INTO `libros` (`id`, `nombre`, `imagen`, `url`) VALUES (NULL, 'PHP', 'imagen.jpg', 'http://php.org');"
    conexion= mysql.connect()
    cursor=conexion.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    conexion.commit()

    print(_nombre)
    print(_url)
    print(_archivo)

    return redirect('/admin/libros')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

esto debido a que estoy haciendo una libreria online con python y flask como framework siendo las versiones

```
Flask -> 3.0.1
Python -> 3.12.1
Flask-MySQLdb -> 2.0.0
XAMPP -> 8.2.12
```

he tratado de ejecutar el cambio de contraseña por medio de comandos que he visto en videos los cuales son:

```
ALTER USER 'migue'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'nueva_contraseña';
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'migue'@'localhost';
mysql -u tu_usuario
```

pero tengo una gran incognita, y es que primero, no estoy ejecutando la conexion a la base de datos con el usuario migue si no con root, incluso cuando ejecuto el comando para ver los privilegios de dicho usuario "migue" me sale lo siguiente:

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `migue`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*9C24103EDF8A5201C8DD6120EC53AC910DD1405F' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `migue`.* TO `migue`@`localhost`                                                                                |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `migue\_%`.* TO `migue`@`localhost`

Trato de hacer el cambio utilizando el comando ALTER USER, pero cada vez que quiero revisar nuevamente los privilegios a ver si cambio la contraseña, me sigue saliendo contraseñas asi de largas y lo mas raro es que cambia la contraseña cada que solicito ver los privilegios.

Comment: LLamas dos veces a `MySQL()`. Seguramente te esté dando error en la primera. Simplemente, comenta o borra esta línea.

Comment: Intente hacer ese cambio pero sigue el mismo error, cuando voy a ejecutar la aplicacion en la web me sale este error MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'migue'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")